# Monitor how many time a method is called?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering if there's a way to monitor the activity of my method(s).

Here are the requirement

**CheckingAccount will charge transaction fees. 
Each month there are 5 free transactions. $3 will be deducted from the checking account for every extra transaction.(Hint: You need to add a method to deduct the fees from the checking account if there are more than 5 in a month. You need to modify the deposit and withdrawal method as well, and you need to add an instance field to remember the number of transactions. You may need to define two constants, one for number of allowed free transactions and the other for fee per extra transaction.)**

So in my main object, I need to monitor how many times an object is called/used?

Here is my main class

public class BankAccount {

```
public double balance = 0.0; //init bal

public BankAccount(){ //create new constructor
}

public BankAccount(double bal) throws Exception { //create new constructor
    if (bal << 0) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else

    balance = bal;
}

public double getBalance(){ //return balance
    return balance;
    }

public void deposit(double amount) throws Exception { //put money into account
    if (amount < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    balance = balance + amount;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) throws Exception { //take money from account
    if(amount < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if(amount > balance)
        throw new InsufficientFundsException();

    balance = balance-amount;   
}

public void transfer(double amount, BankAccount other) throws Exception //transfer money to other acc
{
    this.withdraw(amount);
    other.deposit(amount);
}

public String toString(){ //give info
     String s = ("The balance is: $" + this.getBalance() +".");
     return s;

}

}
```

I also defined my own InsufficientFundsException

Also the 2nd requirement is

**SavingAccount (class) will earn income at fixed interest rate. (Hint: You need to add amethod to add interest each month. Also you need to add an instance field for interest rate.)**

How can I accomplish this on the JVM? I have never used time-based commands before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My Eng is not good, if I'm misunderstanding you can add counter for the method to you want count how many time it called.When the application is exited print the count.

Comment: like :                                                                                                         `private int count = 0;                                                                                 public BankAccount(double bal) throws Exception { //create new constructor
    if (bal << 0) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else
    count++;
    balance = bal;
}`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a built-in way to monitor how many times a method is called. You need to follow the guidelines given in the assignment:

> You need to modify the deposit and withdrawal method as well, and you
>   need to add an instance field to remember the number of transactions.

Assuming CheckingAccount is a subclass of BankAccount, override the methods and add code inside your methods to count the calls.

The other answer is correct, of course, only irrelevant for your assignment: There are a number of profiler tools out there that will count how many times each method is called. HPROF is just one out of many. As far as I can tell, they aren’t relevant for your assignment.

For the SavingAccount class, I don’t think a time-based command is required. Just assume that someone will call your method to add interest once at the end of every month. For testing purposes, you may call it as often as you want (and it will only *appear* that you get rich fast :-)

Comment: I should move the deposit/withdraw method to checkingaccount class (that extends the bankaccount)?

Comment: I think the idea is that CheckingAccount and SavingAccount should be subclasses of BankAccount — would this fit in with what you have learned in class? Then in CheckingAccount, override the deposit and withdraw methods to count transactions (deposits and withdrawals). Will edit.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Oracle HPROF tool

Comment: Profiler? This is a dude asking you to do his assignment.

Comment: He meant monitor programmatically.